# C++ initialization char array by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

In my course on C++ is used this initialization.

```
char *a = "abcd";
```

However, when I use it, a compiler
complains:

> a value of type "const char*" cannot by used to initialize an entity
>   of type "char*"

*a should be pointer. What is a problem please? I use Visual Studio 2017

Comment: The error message just can't be clearer:  a string literal is of type `const char *`, but you're trying to assign it to a symbol of type `char *`.

Comment: @ForceBru actually, a string literal is of type `const char[N]`. It *decays* to a `const char *`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify `const`

```
const char *a = "abcd";
```

The reason is that the string `"abcd"` is a constant and thus should not be assigned to a non const pointer. It was tolerated in old C++ (AFAIK), but since C++11, it's not, and VS2017 with `/permissive-` does the right thing and forbids this bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
 const char *a = "abcd";
```

you forgot const.